# MultiSelectList problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a problem to get the values and text of the MultiSelectList to work. It gets rendered as:

```
<select id="UsergroupID" multiple="multiple" name="UsergroupID"><option>BookingSystem.Data.Models.Usergroup</option><option>BookingSystem.Data.Models.Usergroup</option><option>BookingSystem.Data.Models.Usergroup</option></select>
```

And in my controller I have:

```
MultiSelectList UsergroupID = new MultiSelectList(_ug.GetUsergroups(), u.Usergroups);
```

_ug.GetUsergroups() returns IQueryable, and u.Usergroups is EntityCollection.

Howto fix this?
/M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if you haven't specified the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` of the `MultiSelectList`.